# R plotly(): hovertemplate formatting

Tags: r, hover, plotly

I'm plotting a line graph and need help designing the hover template. I think it should be very easy, but unfortunately I can't figure it out myself.

This is the code for plotting my graph:

```
 p <- plot_ly(dt.dataSpread, x = ~dt.dataSpread$date, y = ~dt.dataSpread$priceDifference, 
              mode = 'lines', type = 'scatter', line = list(color = "#007d3c"),
              text = ~product1, connectgaps = TRUE,
              hovertemplate = paste("<b>%{text} - 'product2??'</b><br>",
                                    "%{xaxis.title.text}:  %{x}<br>",
                                    "%{yaxis.title.text}:  %{y}<br><extra></extra>")) %>%
              layout(title = "<b>Price Difference SPREAD", xaxis = list(title = "Date"), 
                     yaxis = list(title = "EUR/MWh"), showlegend = FALSE) %>%
```

And the plot of the graph looks like this: [image: Hovertemplate-PLOT]

I need help with the **red underlined** part. At the beginning I define two products (strings), but they are not always the same, here e.g.: `product1 <- "EEX ATB Cal-2020"` and `product2 <- "PEGAS Cal-2020"`.

As you can see, I have already defined the first product in the code with `text = ~ product1` and as a text output in the hovertemplate. But unfortunately I can't handle it for `product2`.

Does anyone know how this could work?

Comment: Maybe `paste("<b>%{text} - ", product2, "/b><br>", ....`?

Comment: @stefan, thank you for your help!! Now it's working :)

Comment: Deleted the comment as it isn't producing any other result - Nevertheless, here it is again maybe future readers are interested:
For better readability I'd paste both variables into the `text` argument: `text = ~paste("<b>", product1, "-", product2, "</b><br>")`
Than only pass `%{text}` as the first argument to your `paste` in `hovertemplate`.